# "This file requires `listings.sty' version 1.6"

Tags: listings

I have written my paper in LyX, and exported to LaTeX. When I compile on the journal website, the resulting pdf says:

> This file requires `listings.sty' version 1.6.
>   You have a serious problem, so I'm exiting ...

I have checked my MikTeX and I have version 1.5b. I have uploaded that style file to the journal website, and compiling with that triggers the above error. But I can't find version 1.6 anywhere online, and I can't seem to update within MikTeX.

Any help greatly appreciated! I am not an experienced TeX user I'm afraid, so sorry if this is a trivial matter.

Comment: Version 1.6 is available from [CTAN](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings). Why can't you update this within MiKTeX?

Comment: When I hit edit/Select updatable packages, it's grayed out.

Also - thanks for the link - but there's no .sty file in the zip?

Comment: try changing the repository

Comment: Did you remember to refresh the repository (or whatever it is called in miktex,  AFAIR refresh does not happen automatically)

Comment: @Tom: That's typical of doxygen compilations. You'll have to load `listings.ins` into your editor and compile (with `listings.dtx` also available in the same folder). It should produce a number of `.sty` files.

Comment: Got it - turned out that uninstalling and reinstalling the package worked. Thanks all for your help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is solved by comments.